# Xcode build fails when I try to test app on external iphone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-signing

I was working on an iOS project with an old MacBook Pro and would use my iPhone for testing instead of the simulator. I recently bought a new MacBook Pro and went to use my iPhone for testing and build fails saying "The specified item could not be found in Keychain". If i run the app using any of the simulators the build runs just fine. I tried redownloading all the certificates and provisioning profiles but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: you maybe need to add the new device in your provisioning

Comment: You will need to get the private key for your signing certificate from your old Mac and install it in your new Mac.  If you can't do that then you will need to generate a new signing certificate in the Apple developer portal.